# How get output value in array from each layer Keras

Tags: python, keras

I am a beginner in python and Keras. I am using Keras with tensorflow backend. I want to get value in array from each layer (hidden and output layer) in Keras. How can i do it?

This is my sequential model

```
def baseline_model():
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(1, 28, 28), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation=tempsigmoid))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
return model

# build the model
model = baseline_model()
```

I had tried using this code

```
hidden_layer = model.layers[4].output
print(hidden_layer)
```

but the result in tensor

```
Tensor("dense_1/Relu:0", shape=(?, 128), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the `i`-th layer of a Neural Network you can use Keras functions.
Let's assume that you are training a `Model` on some data `df`:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

# create a Keras function to get i-th layer
get_layer_output = K.function(inputs = Model.layers[0].input, outputs = Model.layers[i].output)

# extract output
layer_output = get_layer_output(df)
```

You can find a practical application [here](https://github.com/IvanBongiorni/TensorFlow2.0_Tutorial/blob/master/TensorFlow2.0_04_Autoencoder_for_Dimensionality_Reduction.ipynb). Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: thankyou for the response. I tried and got error message `AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'inputs' ` . Could it be because my model is convolutional ?

Comment: Reading your error message... did you write `inputs` instead of `input`?

Comment: This is the right way, should be marked as final solution.

Comment: @astri if it worked, please consider accepting the answer as solved

Comment: @Leevo thank you , i have revised my code but it still get error `TypeError: `inputs` to a TensorFlow backend function should be a list or tuple.` I am figuring it now

Comment: Are you feeding a numpy object into it?

Comment: @Leevo i had check my input and i m feeding it with numpy array. I think i should learn it again the process from feeding until output in each layer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing but save the data with that way :

```
hidden_layer = model.layers[4].output
hidden_layer = hidden_layer.eval(session=tf.Session())
print(hidden_layer)
```

That will save directly the Tensor data in the hidden_layer variable.